# An application problem of Maxflow-Mincut or Menger's Theorem

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, network-flow, directed-graphs

Suppose $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph , and let $u,v,w$ be distinct vertices. Suppose there are $k$ edge disjoint paths from $u$ to $v$ in $G$, and $k$ edge disjoint paths from $v$ to $w$ in $G$. The paths from $u$ to $v$ van share edges with the paths from $v$ to $w$. Then, how to show that there are $k$ edge disjoint paths from $u$ to $w$ in $G$ using Menger's theorem or MaxFlow-MinCut.

Update: I have already proved the following statement: Given an integer $k>0$, $G$ has $k$ edge disjoint paths from $s$ to $t$ if and only if there is an $s,t$ flow of value $k$ in $G$.

By the above statement, we know that $G$ has a $u,v$ flow of value k, and $G$ has a $v,w$ flow of value k, but how can we show there is a $u,w$ flow of value $k$ in $G$? This means I have to prove the transitivity of a flow, my thought is to use the flow conservation property of internal vertex to prove that, the internal vertex which joins the $u,v$ flow and $v,w$ flow is $v$. Is this the right approach or there is a better way to approach this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: oh sorry, I have made some edits in the body.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's give an answer using the MaxFlow-MinCut theorem where we assign each edge a capacity of $1$.

The key observation you already made was:
Let $s,t$ be arbitrary nodes, $k\in\mathbb N$.
Then there are $k$ edge-disjoint $s$-$t$-paths if and only if there is an $s$-$t$-flow of value $k$.

Assume, we have less than $k$ edge-disjoint $u$-$w$ paths in $G$.
Then a maximum $u$-$w$-flow must have a value less than $k$.
By the MaxFlow-MinCut theorem there is a $u$-$w$-cut $C$ with capacity less than $k$.
Now we do a case distinction on $v\in C$:

- If $v$ is in $C$, then $C$ is also a $v$-$w$-cut.
  Therefore any $v$-$w$-flow must have a value less than $k$ contradicting the existence of $k$ egde-disjoint $v$-$w$-paths.
- If $v$ is not in $C$, then $C$ is also a $u$-$v$-cut.
  Therefore any $u$-$v$-flow must have a value less than $k$ contradicting the existence of $k$ egde-disjoint $u$-$v$-paths.

---

Now for an answer using Menger's theorem on edge-connectivity.
This states for nodes $x$ and $y$, that the minimum number of edges whose removal disconnects x from y is equal to the maximum number of edge-disjoint paths from x to y.

Assume, there are at most $k'<k$ edge-disjoint $u$-$w$-paths in $G$.
Then by Menger's theorem there are edges $e_1,\dots, e_{k'}$ whose removal disconnect $u$ from $w$.
As $k' < k$, this does not disconnect $u$ from $v$; nor does it disconnect $v$ from $w$.
But then there is a path from $u$ to $w$. Contradiction.